# why do we put the integer in the third place?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

```
from scipy import misc

photo_data = misc.imread(r'C:\Users\user\image\layers.jpg')

red_mask   = photo_data[:, : ,0] > 150
green_mask = photo_data[:, : ,1] > 100
blue_mask  = photo_data[:, : ,2] < 100
```

what I don't understand is why we do `photo_data[:, : ,0]` and not `photo_data[0]` for example.

Comment: Have you tried it to see what it does?

Comment: I believe the first two parameters are the dimensions, so 512x512,rgb. So the `[:,:]` would indicate across the whole image

Comment: A photo is a 3D array: the first dimension is the row, the second dimension is the column, the third dimension is the plane (red, green, or blue). So, `photo_data[0]` would be (all planes of all columns of) the first row of the picture, but `photo_data[:, :, 0]` is plane 0 (red) (of all rows and all columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image is represented as a 3D array:

- Dimension 0 is the row.
- Dimension 1 is the column.
- Dimension 2 is the plane (red, green, or blue).

So, for example, `photo_data[10, 20, 1)` is the green value for pixel `(10,20)`.

So, `photo_data[0]` is all three planes of all pixels in the first row.

But `photo_data[:, :, 0]` is the red values of all pixels in all rows and all columns.

Answer (score 1):

An image is represented as a matrix of triples (R, G, B). The first two coordinates represent the coordinates of an image pixel. The third index represents the channel. When you do `photo_data[:,:,0]` you create a matrix that represents the red values of the whole image.